# Rethrow non-MySQL errors Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

Hi the code below loads a single field from a mysql database, but when it gets to the point **result[0].IdUtente** the error below is generated. How do I solve it?

**ERROR:**

```
 throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'IdUtente' of undefined
```

**CODE:**

```
var query = "SELECT IdUtente FROM Utente WHERE Username = " + sql.escape(Username) + " and Password=MD5(" + sql.escape(Password) + ") and Tipo!='Risorsa' ";
var ret=DbConfig.query(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Errore login: " + err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(result[0].IdUtente);
        IdUtente = result[0].IdUtente;

    }

});
```

Comment: I was getting the same error. Realized that it was due to incorrect SQL syntax. Make sure that you are writing the correct SQL as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error occur when the query pulls an empty result. You must first check the length of result with `result.length` property, only if the result is greater than `0` you must use index the result. 
Please check the code below.

```
var query = "SELECT IdUtente FROM Utente WHERE Username = " + sql.escape(Username) + " and Password=MD5(" + sql.escape(Password) + ") and Tipo!='Risorsa' ";
var ret=DbConfig.query(query, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Errore login: " + err);
    }
    else {
        //check to see if the result is empty
        if(result.length > 0){
            console.log(result[0].IdUtente);
            IdUtente = result[0].IdUtente;
       }
    }
});
```